# maximum a posteriori corresponds to a minimization problem?

Tags: logistic, bayesian, estimation, posterior

I encountered some question related to maximum a posteriori. These questions say finding a parameter which maximizes a posteriori corresponds to a minimization problem. the questions are always binary linear regression. How to show this? Also how to find the object function of the corresponding minimization problem?  Anyone has experiences on this?

Comment: Any maximization problem in $f$ can be transformed into a minimization problem by multiplying $f$ by -1.

Comment: It is obvious, just doesn't make sense by only multiplying by -1. While it makes sense that -Log(f), since log can be easier in practical manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum a posteriori (MAP) is the value of the parameter for which the posterior density (that is a function of the parameter) is maximal. As a result, the MAP is the value minimizing minus the posterior (or e.g. minus its logarithm for practical reason).